# Is there a way for a overridden property to call it's parent property methods?

Tags: c#, .net

```
internal class TestBase
{
    public virtual List<int> testProp { get; }
}

internal class Test : TestBase
{
    class bool filteringLessThanZeroes = false;
    public override List<int> testProp 
    { 
        get => base.testProp.Where(i => filteringLessThanZeroes ? i > 0 : i >= 0).ToList(); }
    }

// the Add calls here do nothing because every time I grab testProp
// it filters and returns me a new list
test.testProp.Add(0);
test.testProp.Add(23);
test.testProp.Add(22);

foreach (var item in test.testProp)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item); // I should get 23, 22 but testProp is empty
}
```

The Add calls do nothing because every time I grab `testProp` it filters and returns me a new list so nothing is printed to the console.

Is there a way I can get the overridden property to somehow call parent's Add method?

Or is the entire approach wrong? If so, how would you implement something like this where when you wanna grab something it filters it out but adding stuff on it works.

I want the same property to behave differently based on the bool property as this property is being used everywhere and I don't wanna refactor that.

I can do this very easily in terms of a string property where I can for instance remove some part of text when they `get` it and concatenate it again when they `set` it.
I just need to know how to do this with lists and other objects with method calls.

Comment: I think you need to separate "list" and "property" in your head. `base.testProp.Where(i => i > 0).ToList()` returns a completely different list to `base.testProp` (and in fact a new list is returned each time you access `.testProp`. The entire approach is wrong.

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar Yeah I figured as much about a new list being returned. Any idea on how to implement this without creating a new property or method for getting filtered lists?

Comment: *implement this without creating a new property or method for getting filtered lists?* Why? This would be logically wrong. [For filtering you should have another class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle)

Comment: I would advise against anything that makes your code this confusing and makes your code work in such an unexpected way, to be honest. Although there are ways you could achieve this, it would change the meaning of how objects behave vs their conventional implementations, and you honestly don't want to go down that route.

Comment: You can make the properties of type `IList<int>` instead, and implement your own `List<int>` that only allows positive numbers, but as Selvin said, this is kind of the wrong solution.

Comment: You want the getter to behave differently when the context is different. A getter cant change behavior easily(non confusing) as it has no parameters. A real Get method has so could behave differently. But using two different Properties to get two different behaviors is absolutely natural.

Comment: You can't do it without creating a new member, because `TestBase` has specified, in its contract, that it will offer a concrete `List` (which doesn't do any kind of filtering), and so derived classes are stuck with that. The essential problem is that you have no control over what happens when `.Add` is called. That means either implementing your own container type (not that attractive, but maintains the interface), or changing the interface so the class is directly involved in adding items (`AddStuff(params int[] stuff)`, and then the property could become a read-only `IEnumerable`).

Comment: @Selvin I've updated the question with 2nd last paragraph to answer the why

Comment: @JeroenMostert I guess I wanted the same property to behave differently depending on the bool

Comment: @dydx As I alluded to, and Sweeper mentioned, you _could_ make your own `IList<>` implementation, and then change the property type to `IList<int>`, but then `.Add(-5)` would behave in an unexpected way: your code would accept a negative value, but it would behave as if that negative value just doesn't exist. `.RemoveAt` would have to carefully skip over such values, etc. It's really not a good design choice. Refactoring is the much better option here, even if it is a more involved process.

Comment: Refactoring is not difficult. First change `TestBase.testProp` to some different name, then rename `Test.testProp` with `F2` and remove `override`, finally change back `TestBase.testProp`.

Answer (score 3):

The problem arises because you are mixing multiple tasks into a single property. You should split them:

```
internal class TestBase
{
    public virtual List<int> testProp { get; }
}

internal class Test : TestBase
{
    public List<int> GetPositiveList() => base.testProp.Where(i => i > 0).ToList();
}

// now you can still use test.testProp.Add(0);
```